# RFID: Why is inductive coupling used instead of EM waves for LF and HF systems?

Tags: rfid, electromagnetic, coupling

Is it because of antenna sizes? At 900 MHz a 1/2 dipole has a size of around 15 cm. That would be far higher for 125 kHz, so instead we use coils to power the transponder and use load modulation for the reverse-link.

Does the low frequency have any effect on reflection? Reflection is dependent on frequency, low frequency waves tend to "go through" materials easier so we would have a harder time reflecting those through the transponder antenna?

Are those the two main reasons?

Answer (score 1):

No, the reason for inductive coupling wins over EM waves for RFID systems is better efficiency at nearby distances. Inductive coupling is a much better way of transferring energy over a short distance. For (really) long distances, EM waves win the race over inductive coupling.

So, it has nothing to do with antenna sizes or reflection.

Answer (score 0):

When we speak of EM waves, we generally mean planar waves. This requires us to be in a region known as the *far field*. The far field is a certain distance away from the antenna, and thus gives us a minimum distance.

If we are talking about reactive (inductive or capacitive) coupling, we are talking about the *near field*. In order to be in the far field at low frequencies, we need very large distances.

The wikipedia article on this can be found here: [Near and far field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field)

In addition, we can extract more energy with reactive coupling (in essence, transformers operate this way, and they go to 99+ percent efficiency). Think of it this way - if EM is propagating, it spreads out as we move away. Our antenna can only cover a small area, and this area is a fraction of the total 'sphere' our EM wave is propagating away from. As a result, we can only capture a very limited part of the wave. This is seen in [Friis transmission equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation)

Answer (score 0):

When speaking about inductive coupling in RFID. The reader emits magnetic field and when tag enters the fild the chip varies its antenna resposnse which will result in a perturbation of magnetic field which can be detected by the reader. The strength of the magnectic field drops sharply with distance from the emitter. Hence inductive coupling is used in a situation where there is a involvement of short range operation.
Also electromagnetic waves causes a lot of interference and other multipath problems.
Inductive coupling works better for high and ultra high frequency operation.